# Unity 5.5.0f3 - Updating an object with ClientRpc throws "Found no behaviour for Rpc call..."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm working on a teammatch game. Each team has it's own spawn and the objective is to destroy the other team's spawn. The spawns are setup in the network in form of 3 objects - an actual spawn (referenced later on to as the **physical spawn**), visible only to the **server**, an object called **MapManager** present in both **client** and **server**, that acts as a messenger through the Rpc calls and a simple graphic of spawn (referenced later on to as the **visual spawn**), present on the **client** and the **server's local player**.

NetworkIdentity settings for each object respectively:

- Server Only,
- Local Player Authority,
- None - is a MonoBehaviour.

The **physical spawn** judges whether was any damage dealt to the spawn and if yes - sets the flag **isHealthChanged** to **true**.

```
public class SpawnerServer : NetworkBehaviour {
    //used to determine whether has the health changed
    bool isHealthChanged = false;
    //indicates the team of this spawner via enum state
    public Data.teams myTeamEnum;
    ...
    public RectTransform healthBar;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        //Checking whether the bullet wll damage the spawn
        OnChangeHealth(healthPoints);
    }
    //if the health changed, change the healthbar as well
    public void OnChangeHealth(float healthPoints)
    {
        if (isServer)
        {
            ...
            isHealthChanged = true;
        }
    }
     //returns the deltaSize of the healthbar
     public Vector2 GetHealthbarSizeDelta()
    {
        return healthBar.sizeDelta;
    }
    //switches the healthChanged bool back to false. Called by the MapManager
    public void UncheckHealthChanged()
    {
        isHealthChanged = false;
    }
    //returns the state of the healthChanged bool
    public bool IsHealthChanged()
    {
        return isHealthChanged;
    }
}
```

The **MapManager** checks for the state of the flag in both **physical spawns** (checks only on the server) and upon detecting the **true** value:

- resets the flag to **false**,
- gets the width of the healthbar,
- passes the info about the new width of the healthbar and the number of spawn to RPC call **RpcChangeSpawnersHealthClients()**, which calls function responsible for updating the data of the transform of the healthbar of the **visual spawn**.

  ```
  public class ClientSpawnControl : NetworkBehaviour {
  //the references to scripts of the server spawns, required for checking whether has
  //the state of any of the spawns changed
  public SpawnerServer serverSpawn1;
  public SpawnerServer serverSpawn2;
  //the references to spawns that belong to the clients
  public SpawnerClient clientSpawn1;
  public SpawnerClient clientSpawn2;

  //acts as a messenger that forces change of spawn healthbars in clients
  [ClientRpc]
  private void RpcChangeSpawnersHealthClients(int whatTeam, float healthChangeDelta)
  {
      if(clientSpawn1 != null)
      {
          if (whatTeam == (int)clientSpawn1.myTeam)
          {
              clientSpawn1.OnChangeHealth(healthChangeDelta);
              return;
          }
      }
      if(clientSpawn2 != null)
      {
          if (whatTeam == (int)clientSpawn2.myTeam)
          {
              clientSpawn2.OnChangeHealth(healthChangeDelta);
              return;
          }
      }
  }
  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
      if (!isServer)
          return;
      if(serverSpawn1.IsHealthChanged())
      {
          serverSpawn1.UncheckHealthChanged();
          RpcChangeSpawnersHealthClients((int)serverSpawn1.myTeamEnum, serverSpawn1.GetHealthbarSizeDelta().x);
      }
      if (serverSpawn2.IsHealthChanged())
      {
          serverSpawn2.UncheckHealthChanged();
          RpcChangeSpawnersHealthClients((int)serverSpawn2.myTeamEnum, serverSpawn2.GetHealthbarSizeDelta().x);
      }

  }
  ```

This is where the exception is thrown: *"Found no behaviour for incoming [ClientRpc:InvokeRpcRpcChangeSpawnersHealthClients] on TeamSelector (UnityEngine.GameObject), the server and the client should have the same NetworkBehaviour instaces..."*

The error is quite interesting, since the mentioned **TeamSelector** has literally nothing to do with the spawners updating. It is used at the beggining, to initialize the team data of the players, nothing more. Even more - one of the **physical spawns** is somehow spawned on the client as well, though if I remember correctly the **Server Only** option should prevent such behavior and I do not try to create the object across the network anyhow.

Earlier I tried to spawn the **visual spawns** armed with **NetworkBehaviour** and **NetworkIdentity** - was getting error about that these objects cannot be spawned in the client, even if I registered the objects in the **Network Manager** and even used the method 
**ClientScene.RegisterPrefab()**. Made every possible combination of the two - situation did not change. Later I rearranged the **visual spawns** to their current form and tried calling the RPC call from the **MapManager** from the **physical spawns** as soon as they detected change in health. Got similiar exception thrown at the client to the one quoted above, but with name of one of the **physical spawns** in the place of the **TeamSelector** object. Search for solutions did not bring up anything that would work, for example I do not have any methods that have duplicate names but belong to different namespaces.

I do not even really know where to search for the source of the problem. After over 3 days of arguing with Unity I feel like it just doesn't want me to create that game. Does anybody know what can cause the problem?

I'm terribly sorry for the length of this post, but I have no idea how to describe this problem in shorter way.